# reference request: compactifying Euclidean space to a torus

Tags: general-topology, compactification

One standard way to compactify $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the "one-point" compactification to the sphere $S^n$. But what if I want to compactify it to a torus $T^n$ instead? What I have in mind is compactifying each coordinate direction to an $S^1$, and then the product $S_1 \times S_1 \times \dots \times S_1 = T^n$.

Is this a standard construction, or does it have a name? Any references to such a construction appearing in the literature would be appreciated.

Comment: That seems like a perfectly well-defined thing to do. What do you want a reference for?

Comment: F. Kost studies compactification of product spaces in his paper [*Wallman-Type Compactifications and Products*](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1971-029-03/S0002-9939-1971-0281159-8/home.html), Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. **29** (1971), 607–612. He shows that products of *Wallman type compactifications* are Wallman type compactifications of their product spaces. Both the Stone-Ceck and Alexandroff compactifications are examples of such compactifications.

Answer (score 1):

It does not have a special name. It is just the more or less obvious fact that if you have a family of spaces $X_\alpha$ and a family $cX_\alpha$ of compactifications of $X_\alpha$, then $\prod_\alpha cX_\alpha$ is a compactification of $\prod_\alpha X_\alpha$.